# Implicit interprocess shared memory on Windows?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, process, ipc, nt

What I would like to do is mark a specific area of memory as being automatically shared between processes of the same image/binary, similar to __declspec(allocate)... and __pragma(section...).

I know that I can use names pipes or equivalent, but for this purpose I would like to avoid system calls or additional overhead. I'm just unsure if there is any way to inform the NT kernel to map a specific range of pages automatically for each process of an image. I haven't found anything on MSDN, though MSDN doesn't include undocumented functionally (by definition), which I am fine with using.

I also don't see any specific PE section names/flags which would indicate such, though it is possible that I am missing something.

Ed: I've noticed that there is actually a PE section flag IMAGE_SCN_MEM_SHARED, though I need to investigate how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.shared,RWS")` and `#pragma data_seg(".shared")` to declare things in a shared memory segment (only works in Visual Studio). See [Sharing Variables Between Win32 Executables](http://www.drdobbs.com/sharing-variables-between-win32-executab/184403303).

Otherwise, if that is not an option for you, the only other way to share memory between processes is to use a Memory Mapped File via `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile/Ex()`. See [Creating Named Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Memory/creating-named-shared-memory).

Comment: I've noticed that there is a PE flag IMAGE_SCN_MEM_SHARED, which those probably use.

Comment: Note that you cannot secure shared sections in binaries. File mappings, on the other hand, use standard access control.

Comment: Mandatory read: [Why .shared sections are a security hole](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040804-00/?p=38253).